# How to stop INotify from updating twice?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I am updating a `Datagrid` and when a user inputs a number that already exists I want notify the user they the number already exists and then clear the value from the `datagrid`.

I know why this is happening, but I can't figure out how to stop this or how to make a work around.

This is very simplified code: Using EF code first with MVVM model.

```
public partial class StaffMasterData
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; } // ID (Primary key)        
    public int? StaffNo { get; set; } // StaffNo        

    public StaffMasterData()
    {
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();        
}
```

Entity extension class for `StaffMasterData` :

```
public partial class StaffMasterData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    partial void InitializePartial()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();            
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

And the method to save the data:

```
public void SaveMasterData(StaffMasterData nwRowData)
{
    using (var db = CreateDbContext())
    {
        //MasterDataBinding is the observableCollection
        //the datagrid is being bound to.

        var staffNoExists = MasterDataBinding.Any(p => p.StaffNo == nwRowData.StaffNo);
        if (!staffNoExists)
        {
            db.StaffMasterDatas.AddOrUpdate(nwRowData);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            Alerts.Error("Staff Number exists");
            nwRowData.StaffNo = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the assinging of the collection changed event:

```
public class ShiftManagerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<StaffMasterData> _mMasterDataBinding = new ObservableCollection<StaffMasterData>();

    public ObservableCollection<StaffMasterData> MasterDataBinding
    {
        get { return _mMasterDataBinding; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _mMasterDataBinding)
            {
                _mMasterDataBinding = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();                    
            }
        }
    }


    public ShiftManagerViewModel()
    {          
        _mMasterDataBinding.CollectionChanged += collectionChanged_Event;
    }


    private void collectionChanged_Event(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += propertyChanged_Event;
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= propertyChanged_Event;
            }
        }
    }

    public void propertyChanged_Event(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is StaffMasterData)
        {
            SaveMasterData((StaffMasterData)sender);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

As it is probably very clear, when running through this line of code `nwRowData.StaffNo = null;` , it fires the event again as the collection has been modified which then in turn runs through the `messageBox` code and it pops up twice.

Honestly I have hit a brick wall with this and any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Set the backing field for the StaffNo property instead of setting the property.

Comment: What do you mean happens when you set the StaffNo property?

Comment: When is your SaveMasterData method called and why is it called again?

Comment: Why check for existing if you use `AddOrUpdate`. It could be fixed with StaffNo constrains on the database and try/catch it. It is possible that an other process could write it between your check.

Comment: @mm8, it fires the INotifyPropertyChanged event. The event is called when I make changes to a cell by assigning the collection to a collection changed event `_mMasterDataBinding.CollectionChanged += collectionChanged_Event;`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, if I am understanding `AddOrUpdate` it only checks for  the primary key?

Comment: In the code you have posted the StaffNo property doesn't fire any event...?

Comment: which property updating twice?

Comment: @mm8, manually setting `nwRowData.StaffNo` to null fires the `OnPrpertyChanged` event. If I am understanding this correctly, when entering data and leaving the cells fires it as I have added data, then clearing it with that line of code then fires it again.

Comment: StaffNo doesn't raise any event at all if it is implemented like in the code you have posted.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Where is the propertyChanged_Event method defined and from where do you call it?

Comment: I still can't see the propertyChanged_Event event handler getting hooked up somewhere. Please post your actual code or delete the question.

Comment: Where does the StaffMasterData class raise the PropertyChanged event, i.e. where is its OnPropertyChanged method actually being called?

Comment: The question remains: Where do you call the OnPropertyChanged method of the StaffMasterData class?

Comment: @mm8, I thought that is what the second `partial class StaffMasterData` was doing that?  The first `partial class StaffMasterData` is in the `Entities.tt` and then I made  a second `class.cs` called `partial class StaffMasterData` to call any methods or add properties as needed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are not calling the OnPropertyChanged method somewhere so I don't understand the purpose of the second partial class. You are supposed to call this method in the setter of the properties but you aren't.

Comment: @mm8, Obviously, I am still a novice,but, being that the `Entities.tt` are code first auto-generated, I read that you should not do anything to them. Adding the partial class allows you to add things like `INotifyPropertyChanged` etc. And since I am assigning the `Collection_Changed` to the bound collection, anytime that collection is changed, ie by doing this `nwRowData.StaffNo = null;` it is firing the event. That was my understanding of it. B/c if I take out the `OnPropertyChanged` method in the second `partial class StaffMasterData`, all events stop firing.

Comment: And I am using the `OnPropertyChanged();` method in the `ObservableCollection` setter.

Comment: So it works if you remove the following line?: nwRowData.StaffNo = null;

Comment: @mm8, when you say works, that line just clears the data the user just entered into the `datagrid`, taking it out stops the event firing twice and everything works as it should. What I think is happening here is, the user adds data, leaves cell, fires the event to save the data or if a duplicate is there goto the `else` and there I use `nwRowData.StaffNo = null;` to clear the data just entered and this again fires the event as the collection has been updated again.

Comment: @mm8, OK, I figured out what was going on, being that this is my first attempt at MVVM, after much research before I actually started on the code, I came across a NuGet package called `Fody` and it employs `PropertyChanged`, so reason why no method was used and the property was being updated was due to the plugin. Sorry about that. I think I am going to uninstall the plugin and use `OnPropertyChanged` method for my better understanding of what is happening. I thought what was happening was normal behavior. Thanks again for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a flag that determines whether to actually call the `SaveMasterData` method. Set this flag to `false` just before you set the `StaffNo` property to null and then set it back to `true` immediately afterwards:

```
private bool _handle = true;
public void SaveMasterData(StaffMasterData nwRowData)
{
    using (var db = CreateDbContext())
    {
        //MasterDataBinding is the observableCollection
        //the datagrid is being bound to.

        var staffNoExists = MasterDataBinding.Any(p => p.StaffNo == nwRowData.StaffNo);
        if (!staffNoExists)
        {
            db.StaffMasterDatas.AddOrUpdate(nwRowData);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            Alerts.Error("Staff Number exists");

            _handle = false;
            nwRowData.StaffNo = null;
            _handle = true;
        }
    }
}

public void propertyChanged_Event(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_handle && sender is StaffMasterData)
    {
        SaveMasterData((StaffMasterData)sender);
    }
}
```